SQL Having condition, when checking 2 columns
In general, I have a working query which is "Having A or B". It works, but I also want to add one more statement. I tried "Having (A and C) or (B and C)" -> gives no user_id, tried "Having (A or B) and C" -> no result.
Here is the working "A or B" query (gets 21796, 21797 user_id's):
SELECT user_survey.user_id 
FROM user_survey
WHERE survey_id IN (2, 8, 12) OR survey_id IN (2, 8, 13)
GROUP BY user_survey.user_id
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN survey_id IN (2, 8, 12) THEN survey_id END) = 3)
    OR (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN survey_id IN (2, 8, 13) THEN survey_id END) = 3);

Pivot table is having some of survey_id with values in value column.
Here what I want to check ("C"):
AND SUM(CASE WHEN survey_id = 18 AND CAST(value AS NUMERIC) > 26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0

so if there is row where survey_id = 18 and value > 26, then take that user_id.
When I add this "C" condition I want to get only 21797 user_id's, but get empty result.
id;user_id;survey_id;value;valn
5111;21796;2;\N;\N
5112;21796;8;\N;\N
5113;21796;13;\N;\N
5114;21796;18;18;\N
5119;21797;2;\N;\N
5120;21797;8;\N;\N
5121;21797;12;\N;\N
5122;21797;18;33;\N

Please help

Why do you need to have OR?  Why can't you just include the 13 in the first IN and remove the OR altogether?

You probably missed adding OR survey_id = 18 to your WHERE clause.

"Having (A and C) or (B and C)" can be simplified to "Having (A OR B) AND C"
Looks like you need
SELECT
  us.user_id
FROM user_survey us
WHERE us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 12, 13, 18)
GROUP BY
  us.user_id
HAVING (
    COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 12) THEN 1 END) = 3
    OR
    COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 13) THEN 1 END) = 3
)
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id = 18 AND TRY_CAST(us.value AS NUMERIC) > 26 THEN 1 END) > 0;

Note the use of TRY_CAST to prevent errors.
If you really do need to distinct over survey_id then do that first in a subquery/derived table, as it's more efficient.
SELECT
  us.user_id
FROM (
    SELECT
      us.user_id,
      us.survey_id,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id = 18 AND TRY_CAST(us.value AS NUMERIC) > 26 THEN 1 END) AS caseC
    FROM user_survey us
    WHERE us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 12, 13, 18)
    GROUP BY
      us.user_id,
      us.survey_id
) us
GROUP BY
  us.user_id
HAVING (
    COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 12) THEN 1 END) = 3
    OR
    COUNT(CASE WHEN us.survey_id IN (2, 8, 13) THEN 1 END) = 3
)
AND SUM(us.caseC) > 0;



"Having (A or B) and C" -> no result

That would be
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_survey
WHERE survey_id IN (2, 8, 12, 13, 18)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING 
(
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN survey_id IN (2, 8, 12) THEN survey_id END) = 3 OR
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN survey_id IN (2, 8, 13) THEN survey_id END) = 3
)
AND SUM(CASE WHEN survey_id = 18 AND CAST(value AS NUMERIC) > 26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;

If this doesn't return any result rows, then there is just no user_id that matches your conditions in the table.
